# Android ListView inside Fragment doesn't display all items. Last displayed Item is cutted of

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

I currently have a bug in my application. The ListView which is inside a fragment doesn't display all Items. Here's a Screenshot:

[Screenshot of the ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCPmU.png)

It should be counting to 50. But it's only counting to 30 (which is cutted of).

Here's my ListView Item Row Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_listview_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my fragment with the listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GeneralFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewGeneral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: show the adapter code

Comment: Set the outer `ReleativeLayout` height to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your fragment layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GeneralFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewGeneral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And your row layout you can simplify like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_listview_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But in my opinion it is better to define exact height of your item row, for example 48dp. In this case your layout will be more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify as below:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewGeneral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> //notice this line
```